# Question regarding compactness in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $$X=\{(0,0)\}\cup\left\{\left(x,\sin\frac{1}{x} \right):x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\} \right\}$$
and 
$$Y=\{(0,0)\}\cup\left\{\left(x,x\sin\frac{1}{x} \right):x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\} \right\}$$
are metric spaces with the metric induced by the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $B_X$ and $B_Y$ be the open unit balls around $(0,0)$ in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Consider the following statements:

i) The closure of $B_X$ in $X$ is compact.

ii) The closure of $B_Y$ in $Y$ is compact.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLxF9.jpg)

We need to find the correct option. Please give some hint for this problem.

Comment: In the case of $B_X$ you can get a sequence of points like $a_k=\frac{1}{2\pi k}$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and points like $b_k=\frac{2}{\pi(2k+1)}$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Look at the corresponding points $(a_k,\sin(1/a_k))$ and $(b_k,\sin(1/b_k))$.

Comment: For $B_Y$ show that $Y$ is closed. You will use that $x\sin(1/x)\to0$ as $x\to0$. Then $B_Y$  is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please [do not use image for the essential part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Do you mean $B_X = B(0; 1) \cap X$? If so, both sets are compact since they're both closed, as the closure of a set, and bounded, as a subset of a bounded set.